# Можно ли как-то использовать прототипы функций в шаблонах классов ? С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

В обычных классах я всегда использую прототипы и затем их описываю.

Пример:

```
class MyClass
{
    string Name;
public:
    List();
};

List::List(){ Name = "..."};
```

Возможно ли использовать прототипы в шаблоне класса, если да, то как?

Comment: Точно так же. Хотя обычно это не нужно (при чем для обычных классов тоже).

Comment: Это считается "дурным тоном"?

Comment: Скорее просто бесполезная трата времени.

Comment: ...потому что определения в отдельный файл вынести все равно нормально не получится.